# How to find the cell address of a range variable in a named range

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to do this in Fortran, but I have since discovered that it would be very helpful to have in Excel as well.

I compare three consecutive cells in a named range.  When the values in the cells correspond to set criteria, I average the three cells.  Then I need to determine the cell address of the central value (cell), thereby allowing me to reference a cell whose offset is dictated by the cell address of this central value cell.

I think it is related to the variable "type" that I declare in the module.

```
Dim CellAddressMin As Range
Dim CellAddressMax As Range

Dim i As Integer

Dim MaxVal As Double
Dim MinVal As Double
Dim Y1Value As Variant, YValue As Variant, Y2Value As Variant

 SOME OTHER CODE

ElseIf (Y1Value >= YValue And Y2Value >= YValue) Then

    ' Y Value is a minimum and need to determine the corresponding time interval
    'The minimum value will be taken as the average of the prior, the minimum and the proceeding values

    MinVal = WorksheetFunction.Average(Y1Value, YValue, Y2Value)

    CellAddressMin = YValue.address
```

Answer (score 2):

For a named range of `test` you could use this code to find the "central" cell - if by "centra" you mean middle value

The code

- finds the median of the named range
- returns the address of this cell from the named range using `MATCH` and `INDEX`

  ```
  Sub GetMedian()
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim rng2 As Range
  Set rng1 = Range("test")
  Set rng2 = Application.Index(rng1, Application.Match(Application.Median(rng1), rng1, 0))
  MsgBox rng2.Address(0, 0)
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Hi brettdj:The central cell is the cell that is either the maximum or minimum of the three comparison cells that progress down a 2048 row column. regards ben

Comment: @user1186621 For the Minimum replace `Application.Median(rng1)` with `Application.Min(rng1)` and for Maximum `Application.Mzx(rng1)`